# Internal Links jump to the end of the slide fragments

Tags: html, reveal.js

In reveal.js, how can I have an internal link `<a href="/#/13/0/-1">Link</a>` which jumps really to the beginning of the slide and not the end.
When I click the link it jumps to `localhost:3000/#/13/0/5`. When I enter `/#/13/0/-1` in the url and hit enter it works..., also when I use `target="_blank"` on the link.

Is there a missconfiguration?
I use the latest master branch.

```
 Reveal.initialize({
      controls: true,
      progress: true,
      history: true,
      hash: false,
      fragmentInURL: true,
      center: true,
      mouseWheel: false,
      slideNumber: "c/t",
      transition: 'fade', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
      width: 960,
      heigh: 540,
      margin: 0,
      minScale: 0.001,
      maxScale: 40,
      pdfSeparateFragments: true,
      hideInactiveMouse: true,
      hideMouseTime: 1000,
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in reveal-code-focus plugin: https://github.com/bnjmnt4n/reveal-code-focus/issues/20